# Difference in number format (comma and dot) on SSMS and SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

I have a numeric(5,2) field on my SQL Server database. When I run the query, the number on that field appears with . (dot) separator. However, when I preview the query on SSIS, it appears with comma(,) separator. I am trying to show the number format with dot(.) on SSIS as well. How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: How are you trying to display this in SSIS?  Do you mean reporting services?

Comment: No. From the OLE DB source's preview. Flat file destination preview as well.

Comment: What do you get when you actually export the data to the flat file?  Dot or comma?

Comment: At the moment comma. I'm trying to get dot.

Comment: i have a feeling it my do with the language settings of either SSIS or whatever you're opening the flat file with, but beyond that I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the Locale settings of the file connection in SSIS are different to the language settings in SQL Server.

In SSIS, go to the Properties window for your File Connection (`Right-click`->`Properties`). There should be a setting for `LocaleID` that will need to be set to match SQL Server (or to English).

Further information can be found in the following [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647532/how-to-import-a-flat-file-without-changing-regional-settings-on-the-deployment-s)